# django and custom dependencies

Tags: python, django, dependencies

I'm working with django and I have some reusable apps installed via pip (django-userena, etc).

My question is if it's better (more useful) to have all this apps in site-packages directory or if it's better to have this apps located in my project root.

I know that dependencies can be satisfied with

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

which is very useful for deploying, but I plan to customize some of this apps. I also plan to use some apps that there aren't in the pip repository (cloned from github i.e.).

What do you think? What would be the best approach? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pip supports installing from Github.

In fact, if you're customizing apps, you should fork them on Github (or wherever) and point pip to the forked versions. See [point 4](http://pip.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user_guide.html#installing-packages) on the introductory docs.

Comment: But what happens if a repository goes down? (project removed from github or whatever) pip wouldn't resolve all requirements... Don't you think it's better to have all the requirements in the root directory so I can backup the whole thing easily? If so... how can i do this? just moving the packages from site-packages to the root of my project?

Comment: It's been a while since I asked this question... As you said the best approach is to clone the repo and then use it with pip like:

pip install git+ssh://user@server/path/to/git/repo:

or:

pip install git+file://c:/repo/directory

if the this is a local repo.

Regards!